# How to find a node using in-order traversal in a binary tree?

Tags: c++

I need to find the node in the binary tree with the value n and return it's link. And I have to find it using in-order traversal only. Why? Because this is a trick question.

I got confused because I believe the only way of achieving In-order traversal is by using recursion. So, recursion automatically has a return statement for the base condition but we also want to return the found node. So, that requires another return statement and it can get confusing.

Node def:

```
struct node {
    int item;
    node* l; // Link to left child
    node* r; // Link to right child
};
typedef node* link;
```

My try:

```
link find(link x,int n) {
    if (x == 0) return; // Base condition for recursion
    find(x->l,n);
    if (x->item == n) return x;
    find(x->r,n);
}
```

How do I return null if the given node doesn't exist in the tree?

Comment: _"I'm not sure if this does what we want it to."_ So did you actually test it? Also please be clear _what you want to do_.

Comment: What I meant is that it is clearly incomplete. I mean, what if the node doesn't exist?

Comment: Also what's `link` please? Sorry my chrystal balls are off for repair, I'm having a bad day :-( ....

Comment: It's a compilation error because the base condition return must return a value.

Comment: I'm sorry @πάνταῥεῖ: I'm such an idiot. `typedef node* link;`

Comment: _@BloodBrother_ Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29567083/edit) to add essential information. Also consider to give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that can be easily reproduced by any reader.

Answer (score 5):

You need to **propagate the link** back if you found one:

```
link find(link x,int n) {
    if (x == 0) return 0; // Base condition for recursion
    link r = find(x->l,n);
    if(r != 0) {
        return r;
    }
    if (x->item == n) return x;
    return find(x->r,n);
}
```

So after you have visited the left child, if that child returned a *real* `link`, you propagate that link upward, otherwise, you continue search. The same holds for the *right* child, although you can trivially return the right childs, results, because if it's `0`, you need to return `0` anyway.

Or the unoptimized variant:

```
link find(link x,int n) {
    if (x == 0) return 0; //we read below a leave, that's not gonna work
    link r = find(x->l,n); //attempt a search on the left child
    if(r != 0) { //we found it!
        return r; //now return what we've found
    }//apparently it's not in the left child, now continue
    if (x->item == n) return x; //hmm, maybe we should check or own value, if it is equal, we report ourself
    //apparently that failed as well, last chance: the right child
    r = find(x->r,n); //attempt a search on the right child
    if(r != 0) { //we found it!
        return r; //now return what we've found
    }//apparently it's not in the right child either
    return 0;//we didn't find anything, so let's return 0
}
```

But the last `if` part can be optimized because the pattern:

```
if(x != a) {
    return x;
}
return a;
```

(with arbitrary `x` and `a`)

Is a pattern that doesn't make much sense. After all if `x == a`, we return `a` in both cases.

Comment: Why have you treated `find(x->l,n)` and `find(x->r,n)` differently?

Comment: @BloodBrother: see comment below the code fragment. You can treat it the same, but it's an optimization. If all actions failed, you need to return `0` anyway. But if the right child fails, it will return `0` as well...

Comment: I'm really sorry for being annoying but I fail to follow. Can you please post the unoptimized code as well right below it so that I can see the differences. Please?

Comment: @BloodBrother: added it with some comment story.

Comment: I love you so much. Thank you for your patience. :)

Comment: I love how you made reading comments fun. :)